# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SQLClient

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sqlclient

> Devo interrogare un DB MSSql da un Progetto Xcode Swift per OSX

Ho trovato una utilizzare una libreria, SQLClient, che potrebbe aiutarmi nello sviluppo ma è scritta in  Objective-C .

Sto tentando di integrare SQLClient , classe Objective C per MSSql, in un progetto Swift per OSX.

Non riesco a risolvere il seguente errore :
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SQLClient

**SQLClient.h (Objective-c)**

```
import Cocoa

class ServiceSP: NSObject {
    let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
    func initConnect(ip:String,username:String,pass:String,db:String,onSuccess: @escaping ((Any)->Void)) {
        client.connect(ip, username: username, password: pass, database: db) { success in
            print("\(ip)===dbb==\(success)")
            onSuccess(success)
        }
    }
    func executeTheQuery(spquery:String, onSuccess: @escaping(_ results: (Any)) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Any) -> Void){
        client.execute(spquery, completion: { (_ results: (Any)) in
            if results != nil {
                onSuccess(results)
            }else {
                onFailure("Unable to get info")
            }
            //self.client.disconnect()
        })
    }
    func disConnect(){
        self.client.disconnect()
    }
}
```

---

**ServiceSP (Swift)**

```
//
//  SQLClient.h
//  SQLClient
//
//  Created by Martin Rybak on 10/4/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Martin Rybak. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString* _Nonnull const SQLClientMessageNotification;
extern NSString* _Nonnull const SQLClientErrorNotification;
extern NSString* _Nonnull const SQLClientMessageKey;
extern NSString* _Nonnull const SQLClientCodeKey;
extern NSString* _Nonnull const SQLClientSeverityKey;

/**
 *  Native SQL Server client for iOS. An Objective-C wrapper around the open-source FreeTDS library.
 */
@interface SQLClient : NSObject

/**
 *  Connection timeout, in seconds. Default is 5. Set before calling connect.
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) int timeout;

/**
 *  The character set to use for converting the UCS-2 server results. Default is UTF-8.
 *  Set before calling connect. Can be set to any charset supported by the iconv library.
 *  To list all supported iconv character sets, open a Terminal window and enter:
 $  iconv --list
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) NSString* charset;

/**
 *  The maximum length of a string in a query is configured on the server via the SET TEXTSIZE command.
 *  To find out your current setting, execute SELECT @@TEXTSIZE. SQLClient uses 4096 by default.
 *  To override this setting, update this property.
 */
@property (atomic, assign) int maxTextSize;

/**
 *  Returns an initialized SQLClient instance as a singleton.
 *
 *  @return Shared SQLClient object
 */
+ (nullable instancetype)sharedInstance;

/**
 *  Connects to a SQL database server.
 *
 *  @param host     Required. The database server, i.e. server, server:port, or server\instance (be sure to escape the backslash)
 *  @param username Required. The database username
 *  @param password Required. The database password
 *  @param database The database name
 *  @param completion Block to be executed upon method successful connection
 */
- (void)connect:(nonnull NSString*)host
       username:(nonnull NSString*)username
       password:(nonnull NSString*)password
       database:(nullable NSString*)database
     completion:(nullable void(^)(BOOL success))completion;

/**
 *  Indicates whether the database is currently connected.
 */
- (BOOL)isConnected;

/**
 *  Indicates whether the database is executing a command.
 */
- (BOOL)isExecuting;

/**
 *  Executes a SQL statement. Results of queries will be passed to the completion handler. Inserts, updates, and deletes do not return results.
 *
 *  @param sql Required. A SQL statement
 *  @param completion Block to be executed upon method completion. Accepts an NSArray of tables. Each table is an NSArray of rows.
 *  Each row is an NSDictionary of columns where key = name and object = value as one of the following types:
 *  NSString, NSNumber, NSDecimalNumber, NSData, UIImage, NSDate, NSUUID
 */
- (void)execute:(nonnull NSString*)sql completion:(nullable void(^)(NSArray* _Nullable results))completion;

/**
 *  Disconnects from database server.
 */
- (void)disconnect;

@end
```

Comment: This is an English speaking site, please translate your question

Comment: I found one using a library, SQLClient, which could help me with development but is written in Objective-C.

I am attempting to integrate SQLClient, Objective C class for MSSql, into a Swift project for OSX.

I cannot resolve the following error: Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS $ _SQLClient